# Who were the 40 men who wrote the Bible?

Tags: bible, authorship

Jehovah's Witnesses believe that the Bible is made up of "66 smaller books". God used about "40 faithful men" to write them. According to them, the first five books were written by Moses about 3,500 years ago; the last book was written by the apostle John over 1,900 years ago. God communicated with the Bible writers by means of the holy spirit. They wrote down the thoughts of God, not their own thoughts. So "Jehovah" is the author of the Bible, according to Jehovah's Witnesses.

1. Who were the 40 faithful men?

Comment: As an answer asserts, this is not peculiar to Jehovah's Witnesses.

Comment: I have re-tagged this.

Comment: @fredsbend not sure that's a good idea, if the OP wants answers about JW, then you can say "the answer is not specific to Jehovah's Witnesses" in the answer, otherwise you're changing the question to match the answer.

Comment: @PeterTurner The OP only tagged it JW. I put JW in the body so that it makes sense with the current answer. [The OP said he scoped it too narrowly](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/to-what-extent-does-this-stacks-exchange-allow-what-is-the-biblical-basis-of#comment4841_2079), so I really don't see the problem.

Comment: @fred I think it's a [gray area](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/gray-areas-of-questiondom).  Where the tag scopes the question unnecessarily.

Comment: OK, I agree with the retag, but not the edits, that looked like an odd sort of bandaid to the context here. I've reverted the original edit and reapplied the tagging. I think that's the right solution. Anon if you disagree feel free to edit again.

Comment: @Anonymous if this question isn't really specific to the JW, would you mind if we removed that entirely (and just said anyone who accepts the 66 book Bible)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 40-author count is not unique to Jehovah's Witnesses, so I'll provide the names of the forty commonly-accepted authors. Note that the authorship of some books (Hebrews, for example) is debated, so the number and names vary slightly depending on which scholars you ask.

1. Moses
2. Joshua
3. Samuel
4. Ezra
5. Jeremiah
6. Nehemiah
7. Mordecai
8. Job
9. Sons of Korah
10. Asaph
11. Heman
12. Ethan
13. Hezekiah
14. David
15. Solomon
16. Agur
17. Lemuel
18. Isaiah
19. Ezekiel
20. Daniel
21. Hosea
22. Joel
23. Amos
24. Obadiah
25. Jonah
26. Micah
27. Nahum
28. Habakkuk
29. Zephaniah
30. Haggai
31. Zechariah
32. Malachi
33. Matthew
34. John
35. Mark
36. Luke
37. Paul
38. James
39. Peter
40. Jude

See [When was the Bible written and who wrote it?](http://carm.org/when-was-bible-written-and-who-wrote-it) for a matchup of names to books, along with approximate dates of authorship.

Comment: So, which one is the hypothetical woman? If I remember correctly, some scholars maintain that some parts of the Bible are likely to be written by a woman or women. It might be one of the canonical gospels. Is this the traditional, conservative account of all the authors? Genesis is accepted as a traditional Jewish narrative, merged from disparate and conflicting sources. Which one of those authors compiled Genesis into a single book?

Comment: @Anonymous: one idea I have heard is that Priscilla wrote Hebrews, but I don't think there is much evidence for it.

Comment: @Anonymous: [found it](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/what-was-von-harnacs-case-that-priscilla-wrote-hebrews).